# How to write a WCF service similar to Running Object Table (ROT)?

Tags: wcf, serialization, ipc, marshalling, com-interop

I am trying to write a [running object table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms695276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like WCF service (.NET 4.0) for providing access to some COM controls across processes. This service is accessed by both COM and .NET clients.

I chose WCF since it is recommended for inter-process communication and I also thought it would be good if I don't have to depend on ROT where I don't have much control over.

After solving several hiccups, I reached a road block. I don't know how to pass the COM control through the service and give it back to a client. The object never reaches the service. Though WCF is recommended for IPC, it does not provide out of the box support to pass COM objects. I also haven't found any solutions so far. May be WCF service is not the right approach to replace running object table. But I don't see a better way to do IPC.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

A COM objref can't be passed around in a WCF message (well I guess you could create a MEOW interpreter on the receiver size and use CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream to pass the objref)

However, you could put the objects in the GIT and pass the GIT cookies around

Comment: Never heard of MEOW interpreter or GIT cookies. Could you elaborate a bit or provide some references? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - MEOW is the wire format of the objref in COM with OID, IID and IPID. This is how COM knows the object and interface with a marshalled COM reference. The GIT is the Global Interface Table which allows you to register objects centrally and returns you an id (GIT Cookie) that you can use to retrieve the object reference as you need it. As long as everything is on the same machine it will probably be simplest to use the GIT as the COM store for your ROT like behavior

Answer (score 1):

But we can directly place COM object into the ROT by implementing IUNKNOWn interface

Comment: Not really an answer to this question. Question is about how to implement ROT using WCF.